# PHP Login - Admin & User based on role

Tags: php

When logging in as user, it directs me to the index.php page. When logging in as admin it still directs me to index.php page. I am not sure the actual issue. I have looked at other posts, but still no luck. Please assist.

user table

[image]

```
//submit
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    //-----variables initiated and set to empty----
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //----insert into database-----
    $sql = 'SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=:username 
    AND password=:password';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);    
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => 
    $password));
    $stmt->execute();       
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   


    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){     
        //$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $_SESSION['SESSION_role'] = $row['role'];
            if( $_SESSION['SESSION_role'] == "admin"){
                header('location: admin.php');
        } else {
                header('location: index.php');
        }
    } else {
        // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
        $noUserErr = 'The username or password is incorrect.';  
    }
}
```

Comment: did you checked  on $_SESSION['SESSION_role'] wether role is set on session or not ?

Comment: `$row['role']` is undefined, because you don't include the field `role` in your sql select statement. You need to `SELECT username, password, role FROM...`

Comment: An aside: I think you shouldn't bother with the $stmt::rowCount(), test against $row instead.  Anyone else want to comment on that?

Comment: Why are you storing passwords in plain text in your database?  Naughty no no.

Comment: What if I go straight to admin.php?

Comment: Aside: Have you initiated a session?  Your session storage may not persist.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't select `role` field. Need to select it to fetch from DB

```
$sql = 'SELECT username,
   password,
   role
FROM   users
WHERE  username = :username
   AND password = :password';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' =>
    $password));
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
    session_start(); // start session
    $_SESSION['SESSION_role'] = $row['role'];

    if($_SESSION['SESSION_role'] == "admin") {
        header('location: admin.php');
    } else {
        header('location: index.php');
    }
} else {
    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
    $noUserErr = 'The username or password is incorrect.';
}
```

One more suggestion to start session if you don't it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

`$row['role']` is undefined, because you don't include the field `role` in your sql select statement. You need to change that to

```
$sql = 'SELECT username, password, role FROM users WHERE username=:username 
AND password=:password';
```

Without that you get a `NOTICE: undefined index 'role'` and `$_SESSION['SESSION_role']` is always false/NULL

*BUT*: **never** store plain passwords in your database. Use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: true, it's `$_SESSION['SESSION_role']`. I oversaw that creative name

Answer (score 0):

You've missed `role` in your query itself. Update your SQL query as -

```
SELECT username, password, role FROM users WHERE username=:username 
    AND password=:password'
```

**That's it!**